# How to mirror a rear camera preview?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, camera, android-camera

I was trying to get the preview of the rear camera mirrored... I mean the preview should mirror images vertically; it should swap right-to-left like the front camera...
I don't need the normal preview i need th image like if it's seen from the front camera and i'm trying the SurfaceTexture.
Is there someone who knows anything about it?
Any type of help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you just trying to flip the picture so that it looks like it would on the main camera?

Comment: Yes i want to flip the preview right-to-left or left-to-right it is the same for me... do you know any method?

Comment: Are you using the camera2api? Or the older one?

Comment: i'm using the older Camera

Comment: So do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did. I converted the array of pixels to a Bitmap and flipped it. I noticed that I also had to rotate my image. If you need to do that you can do so with the rotateBitmap method below. I rotated it before flipping it. Since my application uses both cameras, I first do a check to see if it is using the front facing camera.

```
public Bitmap flip(Bitmap d)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.preScale(-1, 1);
    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(d, 0, 0, d.getWidth(), d.getHeight(), m, false);
    dst.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dst;
}

public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
    //Rotates Bitmap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

So it would look like this.

```
if(orienation == Orienation.SELFIE)
{            
    bMap = rotateBitmap(bMap, 270);
    bMap = flip(bMap);
}
```

Those are just some custom fields I used in my application. I think you get the idea and can cater it however you need.

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            frontFacing = true;
        }
    }
};
```

You can create the Bitmap in your PictureCallback. Just convert the pixel array into a Bitmap. If you use both cameras in your application you can check to see if you used the front one like I did in the example above.

Comment: Also, if this solves your problem, please mark it as so. This will help others encountering the same issue.

Comment: Thank you, i've marked as the answer for now

Comment: do you know how to convert the preview that in my case is a surfacetexture into a Bitmap?

Comment: Just editted my answer @amritsingh

Comment: but i need to flip the preview not an image taken... and the code above works if you have to take a picture... i want to show the preview in a surfacetexture mirrored with the rear camera also @drew